# Match Function Shows Incorrect/Repeat Position

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

The match function is not returning the correct position of the lookup value.

I'm trying to put together an index match formula and keep getting errors. As I do each function individually, I notice the match function is not correct. In the formula, I believe the values that should be returned in Column I will correspond with the row number. I checked the data format, everything is number or text, appropriately. There shouldn't be any repeats, like in cell I1 and cell I2. What's causing this to happen?

See link for image of formula and result.

[image]

Comment: have you tried specifying "exact" string?  `=Match(G1,$G$1:$G$1136,0)`?

Comment: That worked perfectly. Something simple too, thank goodness. Thanks, Scott!

Answer (score 2):

Posting comment as answer to this post can be listed as **Answered**.

```
have you tried specifying "exact" string? =Match(G1,$G$1:$G$1136,0)? – Cyril 14 mins ago     
That worked perfectly. Something simple too, thank goodness. Thanks, Scott! – Katboodle 27 secs ago
```

Comment: I love getting credit for something I did not do. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner it's like a group project!